# Scan integers resources warning

Tags: java, warnings, java.util.scanner

In line 4 of this code, there is a resource leak warning. input=scan();

I want a method that takes an integer from the user. It will ask the user to re-enter an integer value if the value he previously entered is unacceptable, i.e. chars, spec. chars, etc. Also, I want to close the scanner before returning the int taken.

How do I fix this problem?

```
public static int readInt() {
    Scanner input = scan();
    while(!input.hasNextInt()) {
        input = scan();
        int n = input.nextInt();

        while(n<0) {
            System.out.println("Input should be a positive interger!");
            n = readInt();
        }

        input.close();
        return n;
    }
    return -1;
}

public static Scanner scan() {
    System.out.print("Enter number: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    return input;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't create a new instance of `Scanner` every time you want to read something, you should create one instance and keep calling `nextInt()`.

Also, I don't think your loop quite makes sense.  I've rewritten the code slightly - if you want to keep asking the user for a number until `n` is positive, it makes sense to have `n < 0` as your loop condition.

For example:

```
public static int readInt() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = -1;

    while (n < 0) {
        System.out.print("Enter number: ");
        n = input.nextInt();
        if (n < 0) {
            System.out.println("Input should be a positive interger!");
        }
    }

    input.close();
    return n;
}
```

(also, the `Scanner` constructor throws a `FileNotFoundException` so you'd need to handle that in the code above - how did your example even compile?)

Comment: My code compiled and worked as I intended it but it was showing a resource warning. Your revision removed the case of checking whether the input has chars or spec chars. I only want integers to be used.

Comment: @MarcoLau You can ignore the changes I made to the code structure but my original answer still stands: you should not create new instances of Scanner every time you want to read something when you still have an instance which is open.  Reuse the original instance.

Comment: Suppose that the user enters a wrong value. How do I reuse the original Scanner instance to get new values?

Answer (score 0):

Use it with `try catch` block and close it in `finally`

```
finally {
    input.close();
}
```

You should always close your Scanner when you're done with it: